# Mixed state after measurement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, measurement-problem

I'm looking at Section 2.4.1 of Nielsen and Chuang's *Quantum Computation and Quantum Information* were they derive the density operator versions of the evolution and measurement postulates of quantum mechanics and something is bugging me.

Let

$$\{(p(i), | x_i \rangle) \colon i=1,2,...,n\}$$

be an ensemble and suppose you perform a measurement on this ensemble that results in outcome $m$. Then the post-measurement ensemble is

$$\{(p(i|m), | x'_i \rangle) \colon i=1,2,...,n\}$$

where $p(i|m)$ is the probability that the state of the system was originally $| x_i \rangle$ given that the measurement outcome was $m$. It seems natural enough to use $p(i|m)$ for the probabilities of the post-measurement ensemble. However, mathematically, I do not see why that should be the case.

My question then is this: Given only the definition of what an ensemble is and the state vector version of the postulates of QM, is there a way to derive the rules to compute the post-measurement probabilities of an ensemble?

Comment: Good question (and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange)! I'll have to think about this one but I'll see if I can post an answer later. Or perhaps someone else will answer you first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just classical probability theory, note in particular the theorem

$p(m)*p(i|m) = p(i)*p(m|i)\;\;[=p(i\text{ and } m)]$.

Repeat the experiment an enormous number of times $N$. Out of these repetitions, $N*p(i)$ are the state $|x_i\rangle$. Out of these, $N*p(i)*p(m|i) = N*p(m)*p(i|m)$ result in the measurement outcome $m$. So out of the ensemble of $N*p(m)$ measurements that have outcome $m$, a fraction $p(i|m)$ started in state $|x_i\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

The post measurement state is computed in the usual way:
If you measure an observable with spectral decomposition $X = \sum_x x \ P_x$, $P$ being the projectors, the post measurement state if the outcome is $x$ is simply

$\rho_x = \ P_x \ \rho \ P_x $

(up to normalization)

To derive this in a neat way from the original postulate about pure states, you can consider a purification for $\rho$, that is a vector $|\psi \rangle$ larger Hilbert space $A \otimes B$ such that

$\rho = \rm{Tr}_B [|\psi \rangle \langle \psi|]$

$\rm{Tr}_B$ is the partial trace over $B$, an operaton that yields an operator in $A$.
Now, if you measure $X \otimes \rm{id}$ in this larger space, and obtain the outcome $x$, the post measurement state is

$|\psi_x \rangle = P_x \otimes \rm{id} \ \ |\psi \rangle \langle \psi|\ \  P_x \otimes \rm{id}$

It is possible (and easy) to show that $\rho_x = \rm{Tr}_B[|\psi_x \rangle \langle \psi_x|$, as wanted. For further details I suggest you this paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.6815.