# X basis Measurement in a mixed state with pure states

Tags: homework-and-exercises, density-operator, quantum-measurements

$
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left\langle#1\right|}
%
$Suppose that we have a density operator $\rho=\rho_1 \otimes\rho_2\otimes \rho_3$ where $\rho_1 ,\rho_3 $ are pure states and $\rho_2$ is a mixed state. If we perform a measurement on the whole system $\rho$ the state will remain mixed state. I am wondering how the probability outcomes of the state after the measurement can be computed.

For example suppose that the $\rho_1,\rho_3$ is a general state of a two qubit system where $$\rho=\ket{\psi}\bra{\psi}\,\,\text{with} \,\,\ket{\psi}=\cos(\theta/2)\ket{0}+e^{i\phi}\sin(\theta/2)\ket{1}$$ and the $\rho_2=(1-p)\ket{\psi}\bra{\psi}+p I$ where I is the identity operator. How can I compute the probabilities of the different outcomes  of the density matrix due to measurement?

I am considering a projective measurement P where Pa =$\ket{+}\bra{+}\otimes I\otimes I$ or Pb=   $I\otimes \ket{+}\bra{+}\otimes I$.

Is there a straightforward way to calculate the probability of the outcome in a statistical ensemble after the X basis measurement? Some posts claim that the answer uses the classical probability theory ([Mixed state after measurement](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12620/mixed-state-after-measurement) ).

Comment: There isn't enough information here (specifically, regarding what measurement you want to describe) for this question to be really answerable.

Comment: Do you think it is still sloppy or undefined? If so I will erase it in order to write a  specific example.

Comment: Greetings and welcome! Note that the culture in our community is that it's normal and expected for a question to be edited and improved after it's posted. However it's generally frowned upon for a user to delete a question and soon afterwards ask a very similar question — we have problems with people using that technique to avoid our question-review system. In its current form (v5) I don't see any reason for you to hide this question, but it's also fine if you improve it and use the "undelete" button later on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I didn't know if the question is fair enought to be answered. That's why I deleted it. If anyone can help with any literature or example I would be glad. Also if anybody wants more clarification about the problem please comment.